# How to add MySQL support for PHP using MacPorts?

Tags: php, mysql, macports

I installed php 5.3 through MacPorts and now i tried to connect to a database (MySQL)
but always when i'm trying to call mysql_connect(); im getting an error:

```
Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

**My setup is:**

- Leopard 10.5.7

**Installed and active packages via Macports that may be related to this problem:**

- php5 @5.3.0_2+apache2+macosx+pear
- php5-mysql @5.3.0_0+mysql5
- mysql5 @5.0.85_0

I know that this error appears when php is compiled without mysql support
but the package php5-mysql should add this support to php.

I really dont know what i can do.
I tried so many possible configurations but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just at the moment of writing my question I found a solution so maybe it's useful to anyone else:

The problem with the php 5.3 installation via macports is that there is a line in the php.ini thats wrong.

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "./"
```

should be changed to:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; extension_dir = "./"
```

(just uncomment it, right.)

PHP 5.3 finds the extension_dir itself so there is no need for extension_dir anymore.