# MacPorts: MySQL and PHP doesn't connect

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, macports

I've looked through related posts and their suggested solutions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353954/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516739/)) but they don't seem to help in my situation.

I'm running MacPorts 2.1.2 on Snow Leopard, and I've got the following packages installed:

```
php5-mysql @5.3.15_0+mysql5 (active)
php5 @5.3.15_0+apache2 (active)
mysql5 @5.1.63_0 (active)
mysql_select @0.1.2_0 (active)
apache2 @2.2.22_2+preforkmpm (active)
```

I can point my web browser at localhost and it will connect to the default site; a test index.php

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

page works fine as well, so I assume at this point that PHP is functional.  The problem is connecting to the installed MySQL server.  Neither phpmyadmin nor Joomla can seem to connect, and trying a .php test script resulted in problems too.  I'm a bit at loss as to how to proceed from here.

The MySQL server is apparently running:

```
~ > ps ax | grep mysql
10884   ??  S      0:00.03 /bin/sh /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqld_safe
10930   ??  S      0:07.66 /opt/local/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/opt/local --datadir=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5 --user=_mysql --log-error=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/tigger.local.err --pid-file=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/tigger.local.pid
```

and I am able to use the mysql client:

```
~ > mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 15
Server version: 5.1.63 Source distribution

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There's the socket

```
~ > ll /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock 
srwxrwxrwx 1 _mysql admin 0 Jul 31 16:55 /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

and the php.ini contains the MySQL module and configuration

```
~ > /opt/local/bin/php -i | grep mysql | grep socket
mysql.default_socket => /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock => /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock => /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

It all seems to me as this is how things should be.  However, when I try to log into phpmyadmin using 'root' the connection fails, and the same happens during Joomla setup.

Any help, hints, suggestions are appreciated :-)

Comment: Is there some error message with your failed connection? Also the term localhost has some special meaning with mysql. Maybe that's some cause of a problem.

Comment: From phpmyadmin I get: #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server.  And from Joomla I get: Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: Unable to connect to the Database: Could not connect to MySQL.

Comment: So you want to connect via socket or via ip?

Comment: Uh.. I don't know :)  I want Joomla running.  I guess either way (socket or IP) works for me, not sure what the advantage of either one would be.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591978/macports-mysql5-setup-under-snow-leopard) thread which was helpful and let me verify that what I did was ok.

What was missing on my end:

1. I added the `/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock` to the `etc/php5/php.ini` file explicitly.  Not sure if this changed anything, but now all of php has access to the socket:

   ```
   /opt/local/etc > /opt/local/bin/php -i | grep mysql | grep socket
   mysql.default_socket => /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock => /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
   mysqli.default_socket => /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock => /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
   pdo_mysql.default_socket => /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock => /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
   ```
2. I could have sworn I did this, but I tried it anyway: `/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin -u root password '..'` and now both Joomla and phpmyadmin connect to the mysqld.

That's all!  The [Test Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591978/macports-mysql5-setup-under-snow-leopard/7141542#7141542) of the other thread works just fine as well.